# Ensure trivial solution is found to matrix equation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a matrix equation $Ax = b$ with numpy (actually I'm using `scipy.sparse` but I believe the question remains the same). In my setup, $b$ is the derivative of some function.

In my system, it's possible that the equation may sometimes be $Ax = 0$, in which case I want to get the zero vector back. When I try to do this with a vector of floats, the result I get back is a vector of values ~`e-22`. This causes havoc at future timesteps and causes weird numerical artefacts when it should be a steady state. When I manually make the right hand side a vector of integer 0s, I get a vector of exactly zeros back.

How can I do this without having to manually check if the vector is all zeros, and convert to integers if so?

Many thanks

Comment: The `np.isclose` function may be useful for checking if floating point values are near to your zero vector to arbitrary precision: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `np.all` to check if every value in the array is below a certain tolerance value, and if it is, convert it to an actual zero-value vector:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1e-22, 2e-21])
print(a)  # [1.e-22, 2.e-21]

tolerance = 1e-20
if np.all(np.absolute(a) < tolerance):
    a = np.zeros(a.shape)

print(a)  # [0., 0.]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However it seems rather inefficient to do this at every step in the numerical scheme I'm using. I'd ideally like some sort of option for numpy/scipy so that it can cope with returning an exactly zero vector

Comment: This *is* numpy/scipy. `np.all` and `np.absolute` are vectorized functions. Any function in numpy that would do the equivalent would probably work in a very similar way under the hood.

Comment: @TIF Plus the cost of doing this is negligible before the cost of a matrix inversion. So, whatever times it takes, and even if you have a computation time problem, this is not your time problem.

Comment: This use of `all` is already availabke in `np.allclose`.  That's recommended anytime we are using floats.